# Simplest way to animate button in Android menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to code animated menu buttons for my Android app. It will be look something like this:

simple mockup of menu:

[image]

Animation looks like some kind of cube rotation - one spin of cube, something like that..

I'm looking simplest way to program animation for menu buttons (for example "button1"). By on click it have to do animation first, then show content of submenu. "button1" have to be animated by four *.png file:

```
button1.png
button1_step1.png
button1_step2.png
button1_step3.png
```

I tried to find some example in Android SDK, but I hadn't found it.
Anyone know a siple way to code this? Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suppose that you registered those buttons in your activity xml file like following:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="onClickButton1"
    android:text="@string/button1_text" />

<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="onClickButton2"
    android:text="@string/button2_text" />

...
```

Then, add following methods to your activity class. You can describe what will happen on the click of each buttons.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {   
    ...

    public void onClickButton1 (View view) {
       // insert codes here to show animation of button1
    }

    public void onClickButton2 (View view) {
       // insert codes here to show animation of button2
    }
}
```

For animation example, check this link : [I need simple Android animation examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762743/i-need-simple-android-animation-examples)

Comment: Great, I'll check it at home, and comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at http://nineoldandroids.com/

This is a backwards compatible version of the Honeycomb animation class, there is a sample app which does animate buttons.