# How to animate two side coin in Android

Tags: android

I'm going to animate coin (both side) so I have two images and I would like to know how can I animate these two images to get coin flipping effect.

Will be appreciate for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [Displaying Card Flip Animations Android training](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

Comment: I think this is exactly the same as the '3d flip' lib, but that one applies a little zoom out and zoom in to give it a more lively animation :)

Comment: As I understand correct this example animating fragments I would like to know is there a way to animate ImageViews? Thanks.

Comment: I think you can apply animation to any view

Comment: Found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762743/i-need-simple-android-animation-examples and going to use AnimationDrawable is it normal way to do such animation? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it won't be very smooth (depends on number of frames). Also it needs extra work to draw frames of transition (for every screen density).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be a good start :) 
https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that solution.